# Errors on implementing visitor design pattern in c++

Tags: c++

Basically I have two abstract classes `IVisitor` and `IVisitable`, `Product` and `Order` are extending `IVisitable` and Report is extending `IVisitor`, so `Report` can visit `Order` and `Product` and count the number of orders or products.

I get some errors that I can't resolve, such as "function does not take one arguments" when obviously does, unknown identifiers etc.

Here's the code:

IVisitable.h

```
#pragma once
#include"IVisitor.h"

class IVisitable{
public:
    virtual void accept(IVisitor *v)=0;
};
```

IVisitor.h

```
#pragma once
#include"Product.h"
#include"Order.h"

class IVisitor{
public:
    virtual void visit(Order*)=0;
    virtual void visit(Product*)=0;
};
```

Order.h

```
#pragma once
#include<string>
using namespace std;
#include<vector>
#include"Product.h"


class Order : public IVisitable{
public:
    vector<Product> list;

    void accept(IVisitor *v){
        v->visit(this);

        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
            list[i].accept(v);

    }

};
```

Product.h

```
#pragma once
#include<string>
using namespace std;
#include"IVisitable.h"

class Product : public IVisitable{
public:
    string name;
    Product(string i){name = i;}
    Product(){}

    void accept(IVisitor *v){
        v->visit(this);
    }

};
```

Report.h

```
#pragma once
#include"IVisitor.h"

class Report : public IVisitor{

public:
    int numProduct;
    int numOrders;

    Report(){
        numProduct = numOrders = 0;
    }

    void visit(Order*){
        numOrders++;
    }

    void visit(Product*){
        numProduct++;
    }

};
```

Source.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Order.h"
#include"Report.h"

using namespace std;

void main(){
    Product p1("eggs");
    Product p2("meat");
    Product p3("milk");

    Order ord1; 
    ord1.list.push_back(p1); 
    ord1.list.push_back(p2);
    ord1.list.push_back(p3);

    Report *report = new Report;

    ord1.accept(report);

    cout<<report->numProduct<<endl;
}
```

Errors:

```
1>ivisitor.h(7): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Order'
1>ivisitor.h(8): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Product'
1>ivisitor.h(8): error C2535: 'void IVisitor::visit(void)' : member function already defined or declared
1>ivisitor.h(7) : see declaration of 'IVisitor::visit'
1>product.h(13): error C2660: 'IVisitor::visit' : function does not take 1 arguments
1>order.h(13): error C2660: 'IVisitor::visit' : function does not take 1 arguments
1>order.h(15): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>source.cpp(17): error C2259: 'Report' : cannot instantiate abstract class
1>          due to following members:
1>          'void IVisitor::visit(void)' : is abstract
```

Comment: Try to put a space between #include and double-quoted `h` filename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a reference cycle between header files.
To resolve problem don't use

```
#include "..."
```

but use

```
class XXX;
```